# What's wrong with caching in Dynamodb?

Tags: python, caching, network-programming

I have a Python application accessing a web service(DynamoDB). It does 15,000 POST operations but is throttled to 1,000 per seconds.

After adding logging, I noticed that each POST was preceded by a resource refresh returning always the same information.

Here is what the logs looks like:

```
DynamoDB_20111205.DescribeTable: id=... time=27ms
DynamoDB_20111205.PutItem: id=... time=22ms
DynamoDB_20111205.DescribeTable: id=... time=27ms
DynamoDB_20111205.PutItem: id=... time=22ms
DynamoDB_20111205.DescribeTable: id=... time=27ms
DynamoDB_20111205.PutItem: id=... time=22ms
DynamoDB_20111205.DescribeTable: id=... time=27ms
DynamoDB_20111205.PutItem: id=... time=22ms
```

versus the expected:

```
DynamoDB_20111205.DescribeTable: id=... time=27ms
DynamoDB_20111205.PutItem: id=... time=22ms
DynamoDB_20111205.PutItem: id=... time=22ms
DynamoDB_20111205.PutItem: id=... time=22ms
DynamoDB_20111205.PutItem: id=... time=22ms
```

Of course, my reaction was to cache the result of the "DescribeTable" operations as it is always the same (apart from some bits I do not care about) and was curious about the performance "gain". Here are the order of magnitudes of my tests:

- **no** cache: 37.5sec
- **class level** cache: 41.8 sec (shared by all instances)
- **instance level** cache: 41.7sec

I repeated each 6 times under similar conditions but did not attempt any kind of "scientific quality" measurements.

EDIT: Here is a stripped down version of my code. This is highly simplified. In the real version, I use an unreleased version of Boto, DynamoDB-mapper and gevent's greenlets

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class RemoteTableInfo(objects):
    def __init__(self):
        load_remote_table_info() # Triggers the "DescribeTable" in logs

class Item(objects):
    def save(self, table, ...):
        do_some_IO() # Triggers the "PutItem" in logs

class ObjectMapper_with_cache(object):
    table = None

    def __init__(self):
        cls = type(self)
        if cls.table is None:
            self.table = RemoteTableInfo()

    def do_work(self):
        cls = type(self)
        Item(cls.table, ...).save()

class ObjectMapper_no_cache(object):
    def do_work(self):
        table = RemoteTableInfo()
        Item(table, ...).save()

# Slow version
for i in range(15000):
    ObjectMapper_with_cache().do_work()

# Fast version
for i in range(15000):
    ObjectMapper_no_cache().do_work()
```

Why is the **version with no cache *faster* by *4 seconds*** with my "smartest" attempts (class level) ?

Note: I really believe this is related to Python's internals and not to the underlying framework

Comment: What do your data structures look like?  How are you caching the return results?  What's actually going on to create these requests?  Code?

Comment: I think you will need to add more code and detail. What library are you usin (boto?), how did you implement caching, and so on.

Comment: Yes, I had the same question.  Is this using boto?  If so, I'm confused by the persistent calls to DescribeTable.

Comment: I use DynamoDB-mapper over Boto. The repetitive calls to 'DescribeTable' are due to a design flaw, mostly in DynamoDB-mapper. BUT, I am pretty sure the behavior I observe is in no way related to Boto nor DynamoDB-mapper, this is why I almost did not mention them. I believe this is related to the way Python handles class members. Anyway, I'll try to show a stripped down algorithm in the question.